# Wordpress wp.media returns wrong image size in object

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-media

I'm using the following code to open the WordPress media uploader in my plugin. The code works fine and returns the selected image.

```
  /* media*/

    var mediaUploader;
    $('#upload_image_button').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        if (mediaUploader) {
        mediaUploader.open();
        return;
      }
      mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Select Image',
        button: {
        text: 'Select Image'
      }, multiple: false });
      mediaUploader.on('select', function() {
        var attachment = mediaUploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        $('#background_image').val(attachment.url);
        

console.log(attachment.sizes);



      });
      mediaUploader.open();
    });
```

However when I look at the console - the custom image sizes (height and width) in the attachment.sizes are wrong, but the image,  e.g.  An image of 1024 x 1024 reports as 580x580 - but the filename clearly shows 1024x1024.

Any ideas on why this would be the case?

[image: javascript object after image selection - Large size]

edit:
Here is an image of all of the Image sizes in WordPress including 1 from the theme and one I added as a test.

[image: More detailed image]

As you can see the thumbnail , medium and full sizes are correct but large and the 2 added (using add_image_size( 'imagetest', 1200, 630, true ); // Hard Crop Mode) Are incorrect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you change the featured image size of wordpress, or did you add another custom file size? You will need to add the file size as a parameter when getting the image url, if you do not want to use the default size of the function.

Comment: hi, I've updated my question showing the other image sizes in WordPress.

Comment: "You will need to add the file size as a parameter when getting the image URL" where do you add that, and would that explain the discrepancy